# Generate a hash column for table columns on SAP HANA

Tags: sql, hash, hana, sha

I have a table TAB1 (ID, NAME, LASTNAME, AGE, DATEOFBIRTH, ID_CARD_NBR, SHA)

I need to generate a hash for these columns in a column **SHA**.

How to make the code insert/update the **SHA** column?

Thank you

The query to obtain that hash on SAP HANA:

```
SELECT hash_sha256(
to_varbinary("ID"),
to_varbinary(IFNULL("NAME",'0')),
to_varbinary(IFNULL("LASTNAME",'0')),
to_varbinary(IFNULL("AGE",'0')),
to_varbinary(IFNULL("DATEOFBIRTH",'0')),
to_varbinary(IFNULL("ID_CARD_NBR",'0')) )

FROM "MYSCHEMA"."PERSONS"
```

Comment: ID can be  NULL ??? oO

Comment: No! Of course, just a wrong copy past

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Id is the primary key(can't be NULL) you can do this :

```
UPDATE PERSONS
SET SHA = hash_sha256(to_varbinary("ID"),to_varbinary(IFNULL("NAME",'0')),to_varbinary(IFNULL("LASTNAME",'0')),to_varbinary(IFNULL("AGE",'0')),to_varbinary(IFNULL("DATEOFBIRTH",'0')),to_varbinary(IFNULL("ID_CARD_NBR",'0')) )
WHERE SHA IS NULL;  -- or other condition
```